# При каждом вызове функции - новое значение

Tags: winforms, pascalabc.net

Дана вот такая функция и она возвращает случайное число(Она работает)

```
function montekarlo(diap1: double; diap2: double): double;
var
  Xx: array of double;
  i, j, l,k: integer;//количество итераций
  min: double;

begin
  randomize;
  l := PABCSystem.Random(7) + 5;
  Xx := new double[l];
  for i := 0 to l - 1 do
  begin
    Xx[i] := PABCSystem.Random * diap2 + diap1;
  end;
  min := Xx[1];
  for i := 2 to l - 1 do
  begin
    if Xx[i] < min then min := Xx[i];
  end;
  min := Xx[i];
  montekarlo := min; 
end;
```

Проблема в том что она показывает одно и тоже значение.
Как мне сделать так чтобы при новом вызове она меняла своё число?

На рисунке наглядна показана проблема то есть числа выводит но одинаковые(кроме вершины,так как она задаётся с клавиатуры).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И как мне сделать так чтобы числа были не одинаковые?

Саму отрисовку элемента и ВЫЗОВ ФУНКЦИИ произвожу таким образом(таких строк несколько,просто координаты разные)

```
gr.DrawString(montekarlo(diap1, diap2).ToString('N2'), new System.Drawing.Font('Times New Roman', 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 440, 90);
```

Пробовал с применением цикла где задавал количество итераций но опять выводит одинаково во всех местах.

П.С
Вопросы почему Pascal ABC.NET, а не C,C++,C# прошу не задавать.
В задании нужно сделать прогу именно на Pascal ABC .NET.

Comment: `min := Xx[i];` ??? зачем тут вообще массив и второй цикл?

Comment: С помощью 1-ого цикла заполняю массив,с помощью 2-ого цикла прохожу по массиву и каждый раз ищу минимальное значение

Массив хранит все мои случайные числа

Comment: Зачем хранить числа в массиве, если Вам нужно только минимальное? Зачем Вам второй цикл, если после него Вы переназначаете  `min := Xx[i];` (чему в этот момент равно `i`?)?

Comment: Чтобы найти минимальное число,я перебираю массив а i будет моим индексом минимального элемента.
Вся проблема в том что мне нужно как-то на основе входных параметров(diap1,diap2) которые я ввожу с клавиатуры найти минимальное число но чтобы при каждом новом вызове оно было другим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас что, "Range Checking" выключен в опциях компилятора?

Я еще раз хочу обратить Ваше внимание на строку

```
min := Xx[i];
```

после второго цикла. К моменту ее выполнения, переменная `i` достигла значения `l`. Таким образом, Вы вылезаете за границы массива. Поэтому все Ваши манипуляции с генерацией случайных чисел никакого эффекта не имеют.

```
function montekarlo(diap1: double; diap2: double): double;
var
  i, l: integer;//количество итераций
  x: double;
begin
  randomize;
  l := PABCSystem.Random(7) + 5;
  result := PABCSystem.Random * diap2 + diap1;
  for i := 1 to l - 1 do
  begin
    x := PABCSystem.Random * diap2 + diap1;
    if x < result then
      result := x;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Да у меня выскакивало исключение про границы массива,но не каждый раз а например через 4-5 раз.
Я это учту.